# SpringWebflow: Setting values in RequestContext -> httpServletRequest is not accessible at JSP

Tags: spring-webflow

I am setting some values in request in my action/controller class like this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getNativeRequest();
request.setAttribute("testKey", "testValue");
```

But when I tried to retrieve this from JSP, I am getting null value.

```
<%
String testKey = ""+request.getAttribute("testKey");
%>
```

Any idea, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found 2 ways to do this:
1) Using a same modelAttribute in and assign values back and forth
2) setting values into context.getFlowScope().put(KEY,OBJECT);
   And retrieving this value (OBJECT) from JSP using ${KEY}.